# Does chat-gpt have an unconscious?

Tags: consciousness, artificial-intelligence, qualia, psychoanalysis

Does chat-gpt have an unconscious? Do you need qualia (which I feel chat-gpt lacks, though in reality I don't know what it *is*, rather than what it outputs) to have an unconscious, or just the capacity for processing data?

I think maybe, and it depends on how you elaborate 'unconscious'. It may well be that mountains and rocks are buddha nature and that this overlaps entirely with the buddhist unconscious, but all of this is extremely metaphorical and will be answered with a "no" if we mean "human".

Comment: I think unconscious is all that it has -- all that it is. Our own unconscious is a deep learning AI, much like ChatGPT.

Comment: ha i like that a lot @YuriZavorotny

Comment: To have an unconscious it would need to first have a conscious.

Comment: what is consciousness in freudian analysis e,g. @armand

Comment: Shame this was closed. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @CriglCragl thanks! i was wondering if AI will struggle with (processing) unconscious human interaction. we don't necessarily understand it, are less able to communicate about (and so teach) it, etc.. i suspect that some amouunt of the image insanity is due to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While “the unconscious” is a useful way of describing certain aspects of a human mind, it's not entirely clear how it would describe things that are *not* human minds. At heart, this is a question about [philosophy-of-language](/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-language). If a tree falls in a forest, does it make a sound?

It depends what you mean by “an unconscious”. I suspect, once you have answered *that*, there will be no more question.

Comment: thus is always the way... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No. An unconscious cannot exist without a consciousness. The "unconscious" is the non-conscious *part of a conscious intellect* which stores info to be accessed by its corresponding consciousness. Chat gpt has no unconscious, just as how a rock has no unconscious.

Comment: no evidence of reverse transference in its therapies then...